# Backpropagate through a tensorflow linspace

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, backpropagation

I have a tensorflow variable defined as

```
    tf_y_min = tf.reduce_min(tf_f)
    tf_y_max = tf.reduce_max(tf_f)
    tf_ydelta = (tf_y_max-tf_y_min)/(Ny-1)
    tf_y_linspace = tf.linspace(tf_y_min,tf_y_max,Ny)
```

where `tf_f` is the output of a neural network. However, I am not able to calculate the gradient with respect to the weights of the neural network,

```
tf.gradients(tf_y_linspace,tf_weights)
```

I get the error, `Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>`

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is this even supposed to mean? What result do you expect? How should such a gradient be interpreted?

Comment: As you move `y_min` and `y_max` , all the elements of the linspace will move accordingly (since each of them is equally spaced by ` ydelta`